# How do I select a certain View Mode for user edit page?

Tags: entities, users

I am looking to create a paged user registration process but I would like the user edit page to be as normal.

I have tried [Multi Step Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step), but there is compatibility issues with [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan).

I was thinking of using [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) to create the pages for the registration, but I do not want the user edit page to use these Field Grouped pages as well. If I could create a custom View Mode where 1 would be for User Registration and 1 would be for User Edit, I think this would solve my problem.

I would use [Entity View Modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) to create the additional view mode, but how do I set the view mode for the User Edit page?